# Can you copy an existing div to a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a dashboard with multiple panels to display different information and I would like to be able to add a button to display the panel in a modal.

I am using bootstrap and all I can find is modals already written. I would like to copy the content of a div tag which is a panel and then display that in the model, but I am unsure as how to go about it. The html for the panel can be seen below. The panel does contain a table but I have cut the code down. I have looked around but I can't seem to find a solution for what I need. I understand that I need to use jQuery, copy the panel and add it to the contents of the modal dialog. I have tried to do this but had no luck. I have included a fiddle to show the approach I have taken [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qsbkqc9m/) this does launch the modal but the content is not displayed nor the button to close it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML code for the panel:**

```
<div class="panel sample panel-yellow message">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa fa-flask fa-fw"></i>Sample Updates 
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin sample "></i>
            <a id="refreshMessage" class="refreshButton pull-right" href="#"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span></a>
            <a id="hideMessage" class="refreshButton pull-right" href="#"><span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span></a>
            <a id="focusMessage" class="focusButton pull-right" href="#"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <center>
            <h5 class="text-warning">Table shows samples created or modified in the last ten minutes</h5>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot of the panel I want to display:**
[image: Panel i need to copy to modal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try this

```
<div class="panel sample panel-yellow message">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <i class="fa fa-flask fa-fw"></i>Sample Updates <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin sample ">
                        </i>
                        <a id="refreshMessage" class="refreshButton pull-right" href="#"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span></a>
                        <a id="hideMessage" class="refreshButton pull-right" href="#"><span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span></a>
                        <a id="focusMessage" class="focusButton pull-right" href="#"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                    </h3>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    New Samples
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Modified Samples
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="sampleCount"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="sampleCount2"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <h5 class="text-warning">
                            Table shows samples created or modified in the last ten minutes</h5>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>


<div id="SampleModal" class="modal fade" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
```

Only Change in Mark Up is I removed the class hide

```
$('.focusButton').click(function(){
    var newRow = $(this).parent().parent().parent('.sample').clone();
    $('#SampleModal .modal-body').html(newRow);
    $('#SampleModal').modal();
});
```

Check This Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/qsbkqc9m/12/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the following code

Using JQuery:

```
var html = $(id).html();
```

Using Javascript:

```
var html = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is obvious but I'm saying it anyway for completeness; he would also need to specify an id for the div that he wants to copy the html from..