# Show selected chart in a resizable modal

Tags: dc.js

I have several dc.js charts in a dashboard and would like to allow the user to view a selected chart is a modal window that can be resized.  Does anyone have suggestions or examples?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is dc.js related exactly. More a html / javascript solution for showing a modal and providing resize options - then writing extra javascript so the dc.js chart resizes nicely with the modal.

Does it have to be a modal? An easier solution, in my opinion, would be to provide the ability to expand/resize/drag n drop the existing chart div - this can be done using a javascript library like  [gridster.js](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/)

Comment: Thanks,  I was being a little lazy and checking to see if someone already had a reuse function that placed the currently selected chart into a modal so the user could look at the chart in more detail rather than in a crowded dashboard.

I have looked at gridster.js a couple months ago but have not had the chance to integrated into a couple of our pages.  When I was relooking at it this weekend I also found gridstack which seems to be more active.  Will probably play around with some test cases tomorrow.

Comment: Did you find anything that did the job you needed?

I found this question that seems to work for a modal that displays an existing div [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544575/can-you-copy-an-existing-div-to-a-modal-dialog)

I also used jQuery UI 'sortable portlets' for drag and drop functionality - [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets)